# How to create additional istio ingress gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We are using the default ingress gateway for istio. We would like to create two different ingress gateway for using private and public external load balancer.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this example](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/multi-mesh-examples/tree/master/add_hoc_limited_trust#deploy-a-private-ingress-gateway-in-the-second-cluster), step 3: *Deploy a private ingress gateway and mount the new secrets as data volumes by the following command*. You may want to edit the helm values of the example, for example remove the mounted volumes with the certificates, change the name of the gateway, the namespace it is deployed to.

Comment: Seems, It's not documented properly. I am using helm. Can you share the steps to create?

Comment: The steps are in the example: https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/multi-mesh-examples/tree/master/add_hoc_limited_trust#deploy-a-private-ingress-gateway-in-the-second-cluster