# ImagePullBackOff with Istio/X when attempting to create a new Istio Ingress Gateway in 2024

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I am currently using the default Ingress Gateway of Istio, but I want to create more gateways in order to have one LoadBalancer per service. I would like to create a Helm chart to facilitate their creation.

I have tried several configurations, such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859624/how-to-create-additional-istio-ingress-gateway?rq=3) or this [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835752/how-to-create-custom-istio-ingress-gateway-controller?rq=3), but I wasn't able to create a second Ingress. The main error that I encountered was:

```
 cat <<EOF | helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio/ --name istio --namespace istio-private-gateways -x charts/gateways/templates/deployment.yaml -x charts/gateways/templates/service.yaml -x charts/gateways/templates/serviceaccount.yaml -x charts/gateways/templates/autoscale.yaml -x charts/gateways/templates/role.yaml -x charts/gateways/templates/rolebindings.yaml --set global.istioNamespace=istio-system -f - | kubectl apply --context=$CTX_CLUSTER1 -f -
> gateways:
>   enabled: true
>   istio-egressgateway:
>     enabled: false
>   istio-ingressgateway:
>     enabled: false
>   istio-private-egressgateway:
>     enabled: true
>     labels:
>       app: istio-private-egressgateway
>       istio: private-egressgateway
>     replicaCount: 1
>     autoscaleMin: 1
>     autoscaleMax: 5
>     cpu:
>       targetAverageUtilization: 80
>     type: ClusterIP
>     ports:
>     - port: 80
>       name: http
>     - port: 443
>       name: https
>     - port: 15444
>       name: tls-for-cross-cluster-communication
>     - port: 31400
>       name: tcp-1
>     - port: 31401
>       name: tcp-2
>     secretVolumes:
>     - name: c1-example-com-certs
>       secretName: c1-example-com-certs
>       mountPath: /etc/istio/c1.example.com/certs
>     - name: c1-trusted-certs
>       secretName: c1-trusted-certs
>       mountPath: /etc/istio/example.com/certs
> EOF
Error: unknown flag: --name
error: no objects passed to apply
&
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'x' in -x
error: no objects passed to apply
```

So I tried to update the template from the Istio default [Ingress Gateway](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/3a0daf1db0bd8a98a414abf7c21e9506a0839848/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/gateways/templates) :

```
Deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingressgateway-beta
  namespace: beta-v2
  labels:
    istio: ingressgateway-beta
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway-beta
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        istio: ingressgateway-beta
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
        # scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod is deprecated, consider using priorityClassName instead
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: beta-ingressgateway-service-account
      tolerations:
      - key: "env"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "beta"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
      #nodeSelector:
      #  env: beta
      containers:
        - name: istio-proxy
          image: "istio/pilot"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
          args:
          - proxy
          - router
          - -v
          - "2"
          - --discoveryRefreshDelay
          - '1s' #discoveryRefreshDelay
          - --drainDuration
          - '45s' #drainDuration
          - --parentShutdownDuration
          - '1m0s' #parentShutdownDuration
          - --connectTimeout
          - '10s' #connectTimeout
          - --serviceCluster
          - ingressgateway-beta
          - --zipkinAddress
          - zipkin.istio-system:9411
          - --proxyAdminPort
          - "15000"
          - --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
          - NONE
          - --discoveryAddress
          - istio-pilot.istio-system:8080
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
          env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                apiVersion: v1
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                apiVersion: v1
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          - name: INSTANCE_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                apiVersion: v1
                fieldPath: status.podIP
          - name: ISTIO_META_POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          volumeMounts:
          - name: istio-certs
            mountPath: /etc/certs
            readOnly: true
          - name: ingressgateway-beta-certs
            mountPath: "/etc/istio/ingressgateway-beta-certs"
            readOnly: true
          - name: ingressgateway-beta-ca-certs
            mountPath: "/etc/istio/ingressgateway-beta-ca-certs"
            readOnly: true
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
      - name: istio-certs
        secret:
          secretName: istio.beta-ingressgateway-service-account
          optional: true
      - name: ingressgateway-beta-certs
        secret:
          secretName: "istio-ingressgateway-beta-certs"
          optional: true
      - name: ingressgateway-beta-ca-certs
        secret:
          secretName: "istio-ingressgateway-beta-ca-certs"
          optional: true
      affinity: {}
      #  nodeAffinity:
      #    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      #      nodeSelectorTerms:
      #      - matchExpressions:
      #        - key: kubernetes.io/arch  # Use kubernetes.io/arch instead of beta.kubernetes.io/arch
      #          operator: In
      #          values:
      #          - amd64
      #          - ppc64le
      #          - s390x
      #    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      #    - weight: 2
      #      preference:
      #        matchExpressions:
      #        - key: kubernetes.io/arch  # Use kubernetes.io/arch instead of beta.kubernetes.io/arch
      #          operator: In
      #          values:
      #          - amd64
```

```
service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingressgateway-beta
  namespace: beta-v2
  annotations:
  labels:
    istio: ingressgateway-beta
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway-beta
  ports:
    -
      name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    -
      name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
```

```
serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: beta-ingressgateway-service-account
  namespace: beta-v2
  labels:
    app: ingressgateway-beta
```

After applying those three .yaml files, I have one working LoadBalancer and one correct ServiceAccount. However, I am encountering some issues with the image for the deployment. I have tried using istio/proxy, istio/proxyv2, istio/proxyv2:1.12.5-distroless, and the latest one istio/pilot, but none of them have worked.

I don't think the issue is related to the way I created my imagePullSecrets because I followed the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) closely.

[image: imagePullBackOff]

```
kubectl version
Client Version: v1.29.1
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.28.3
```

istio-1.20.3

To summarize: I'm looking for an alternative method to create a custom Ingress Gateway that works, or assistance in troubleshooting my current configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a [good tutorial from 2020](https://learncloudnative.com/blog/2020-01-09-deploying_multiple_gateways_with_istio) that provided me with this architecture.

```
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
    istio: my-gateway-custom-name-ingressgateway
    istio.io/rev: default
    operator.istio.io/component: IngressGateways
    release: istio
  name: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        averageUtilization: 80
        type: Utilization
    type: Resource
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
    istio: my-gateway-custom-name-ingressgateway
    istio.io/rev: default
    operator.istio.io/component: IngressGateways
    release: istio
  name: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
      istio: my-gateway-custom-name-ingressgateway
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 100%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        istio.io/rev: default
        prometheus.io/path: /stats/prometheus
        prometheus.io/port: "15020"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
      labels:
        app: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
        chart: gateways
        heritage: Tiller
        install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
        istio: my-gateway-custom-name-ingressgateway
        istio.io/rev: default
        operator.istio.io/component: IngressGateways
        release: istio
        service.istio.io/canonical-name: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
        service.istio.io/canonical-revision: latest
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: null
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: null
      containers:
      - args:
        - proxy
        - router
        - --domain
        - $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
        - --proxyLogLevel=warning
        - --proxyComponentLogLevel=misc:error
        - --log_output_level=default:info
        env:
        - name: JWT_POLICY
          value: third-party-jwt
        - name: PILOT_CERT_PROVIDER
          value: istiod
        - name: CA_ADDR
          value: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: INSTANCE_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: HOST_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
        - name: ISTIO_CPU_LIMIT
          valueFrom:
            resourceFieldRef:
              resource: limits.cpu
        - name: SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
        - name: ISTIO_META_WORKLOAD_NAME
          value: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
        - name: ISTIO_META_OWNER
          value: kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
        - name: ISTIO_META_MESH_ID
          value: cluster.local
        - name: TRUST_DOMAIN
          value: cluster.local
        - name: ISTIO_META_UNPRIVILEGED_POD
          value: "true"
        - name: ISTIO_META_CLUSTER_ID
          value: Kubernetes
        - name: ISTIO_META_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        image: docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.20.3
        name: istio-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 15021
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 15090
          name: http-envoy-prom
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 30
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz/ready
            port: 15021
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 2
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 2000m
            memory: 1024Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
          privileged: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/workload-spiffe-uds
          name: workload-socket
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/credential-uds
          name: credential-socket
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/workload-spiffe-credentials
          name: workload-certs
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/proxy
          name: istio-envoy
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/config
          name: config-volume
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/istio
          name: istiod-ca-cert
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/tokens
          name: istio-token
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /var/lib/istio/data
          name: istio-data
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/pod
          name: podinfo
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs
          name: ingressgateway-certs
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs
          name: ingressgateway-ca-certs
          readOnly: true
      securityContext:
        runAsGroup: 1337
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1337
      serviceAccountName: istio-ingressgateway-service-account
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: workload-socket
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: credential-socket
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: workload-certs
      - configMap:
          name: istio-ca-root-cert
        name: istiod-ca-cert
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.labels
            path: labels
          - fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.annotations
            path: annotations
        name: podinfo
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: istio-envoy
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: istio-data
      - name: istio-token
        projected:
          sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              audience: istio-ca
              expirationSeconds: 43200
              path: istio-token
      - configMap:
          name: istio
          optional: true
        name: config-volume
      - name: ingressgateway-certs
        secret:
          optional: true
          secretName: istio-ingressgateway-certs
      - name: ingressgateway-ca-certs
        secret:
          optional: true
          secretName: istio-ingressgateway-ca-certs
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
    istio: my-gateway-custom-name-ingressgateway
    istio.io/rev: default
    operator.istio.io/component: my-gateway-custom-name-IngressGateways
    release: istio
  name: my-gateway-custom-name-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
      istio: my-gateway-custom-name-ingressgateway
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations: null
  labels:
    app: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
    istio: my-gateway-custom-name-ingressgateway
    istio.io/rev: default
    operator.istio.io/component: IngressGateways
    release: istio
  name: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  ports:
  - name: status-port
    port: 15021
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15021
  - name: http2
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: my-gateway-custom-name-istio-ingressgateway
    istio: my-gateway-custom-name-ingressgateway
  type: LoadBalancer

---
```

And it works as expected!
Now, you just have to change the 'my-gateway-custom-name-ingressgateway' to whatever you want.